# 70 % of all Numbers -> 1

Tags: r, distribution, sample

Whats the most effective solution for that problem?
A sample of 100 "0" and "1".

```
sample(0:1, 100, replace=TRUE, prob=NULL)
```

A) 70% of all generated numbers should be "1".

B) 80% of all generated numbers should be "1".

Whats the argument/or library that allows such kind of distribution?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what do you suppose the `prob` argument is for?

Comment: :) I know, but "prob = 0,7" or "prob = 0,8" == wrong argument!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about:

```
rbinom(1, n = 100, prob = .7)
```

Comment: No. That gives "74". But what I need is 70% of all generated numbers should "1".

Comment: @user2802772 - Sry, I had a typo there but already fixed that a few mins ago. Pls try again.

Answer (score 6):

To get exactly x apples and y oranges, you can build such vector and sample it:

```
sample(c(rep("apple", x), rep("orange", y)))
```

In your case:

```
sample(c(rep(1, 70), rep(0, 100 - 70)))
```

Comment: Good luck making that work if the p-value associated with 1's is an irrational number.

Comment: @pjs: OP specifically mentioned a sample size of 100, and wanting 70% or 80% of 1s. Making a comment about how my solution won't generalize **outside** the OP's case is fine (maybe without the snobish *good luck*), but down-voting is lame.

Comment: Sample size is irrelevant if the proportion of 1's should be 1/PI, for example - you'd need a massive array to get a decent rational approximation to 1/Pi, even though you only want to sample 100. Your proposal is inefficient on space and doesn't work in general. What's the point of telling people how to do something poorly in a special case when there are solutions that are more efficient and generalize?

Comment: OP's question can be interpreted as how do I get *exactly* 70 or 80 1's in a vector of length 100. Other methods do not guarantee that as @Ananda kindly showed using `table`. Excuse me if I am trying to contribute, while you are trying to show how smart you are in a derogatory manner.

Comment: OP's attempt had sampling with replacement, indicating that s/he wanted the proportion of 1's to be 70% or 80% rather than a shuffle of 100 numbers, 70% or 80% of which were 1's. So no, it shouldn't be interpreted as how do I get _exactly_ 70 or 80 1's in a vector of length 100.

Comment: @pjs, after seeing their comment to daroczig, I was sort of thinking that flodel was spot-on with this answer.

Comment: @AnandaMahto Flodel started off with "To get exactly x apples and y oranges...".  I agree that the subsequent answer covers that scenario, but if you're sampling with replacement you shouldn't expect to get exactly 70 1's. Hence in my view flodel was not answering the question that was asked.

Answer (score 4):

From your comment, it seems like you might just be using `prob` incorrectly.

Consider the following:

```
set.seed(1); x <- sample(0:1, 100, replace=TRUE, prob=c(.3, .7)); table(x)
# x
#  0  1 
# 32 68 
set.seed(2); x <- sample(0:1, 100, replace=TRUE, prob=c(.3, .7)); table(x)
# x
#  0  1 
# 31 69 
set.seed(1); x <- sample(0:1, 100, replace=TRUE, prob=c(.2, .8)); table(x)
# x
#  0  1 
# 17 83 
set.seed(2); x <- sample(0:1, 100, replace=TRUE, prob=c(.2, .8)); table(x)
# x
#  0  1 
# 23 77
```